# Deleting old user settings

Tags: .net, settings

I am using the standard .NET Settings functionality, which allows be to store settings under the user and application scope.

I have noticed that every time I do an installation of a new build it creates a new folder for the settings and a new settings file.

I have worked out how to use the Upgrade method update the new settings with the old ones. However I want to delete the old folders so they don't clutter up the system.

I could manually delete the files and folders using the IO Functionalities of .NET, but I was wondering if there is an in built way for the Settings functionality.

Does anyone know the answer?

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: Nobody goes in there, why not just leave 'em be?

Comment: @Will - because you're cluttering up the user's computer with obsolete files. And the kind of user who *does* go in there is the kind of user who will be peeved because of this.

Comment: @Jon You are itching to fix stuff that isn't broken.  Any normal functioning pooter is chock a block with obsolete files.  Some of them aren't even tucked away in a hidden folder like the settings files are.  If some user complained to me about that I'd say "well, you can delete all of them except the last folder; that should save you about 20k on your disk."  Its just not worth the time and effort to actually do this.

Comment: @Jon there is a security issue as well as some of the data stored is the login username.

Besides we believe in perfection, attention to detail and giving out customers 100% satisfaction with our products.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

A non-direct answer is that using a custom **SettingsProvider** to create the settings in a place like

> AppData\Local\CompanyName\ProductName\

without the default version name and other hash strings.

In this way you can always ensure that you're using one user settings. The downside is that you might run into issues like collisions with other apps or spoofing.